# Socket io namespace server emit three times to client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Hi i have been looking through questions here on why my socket io server is emitting three times to the client.

DISCLAIMER: this is not a duplicate question, please view my issue carefully

This is how i bind the server to express

```
var server = http.createServer(app);

 var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
//var io = require('socket.io')(http);
require('./routes/sock')(io);


//server.listen(port);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

Now this is how i listen in my `routes/sock` file, i simply create a namespace and start listening for events

```
module.exports = function (io) {

    var chat = io.of('/chat');

    chat.on('connection', function (cs) {

        console.log('User Connected to chat');

        // save client id
        var socketid = cs.id;
        chat.setMaxListeners(0);

        cs.on('my message', function (event) {
            chat.to(socketid).emit('my message', 'for your eyes only');
        });

        cs.on('second message', function (event) {
            chat.to(socketid).emit('second message', 'for your eyes only');
        });

       cs.on('third message', function (event) {
            chat.to(socketid).emit('third message', 'for your eyes only');
        });

      .....
      //other events follow with the same flow
    })
}
```

**Analysis**

On the client side, i have logs and the client is emitting only once,
However when the server responds it emits three times to the client, making the client listener fire three times

**What am i doing wrong?** 
This is not a duplicate question please, no one is having the same issues with namespaces.

Comment: Are you calling `require('./routes/sock')(io);` more than once?  It does not appear that you've disclosed the code that would cause this issue so the problem must be elsewhere in other code that you have not shown.

Comment: @jfriend00 Am only calling the `require('./routes/sock')(io);` once from my main file where i start the express server

Comment: Well, I don't see a cause for the problem you've described in the code you've shown.  There must be an issue in other code that you have not yet shown.

Comment: @jfriend00 i have edited the question, please check, all my other code continue in the same flow, but when the server emits, the client receives it three times

Comment: @user568109 would you help with this issue

Comment: @jfriend00 this is quite strange, some of my events are only emitted once, but some event is fired thrice

Comment: My wild guess is a client problem with event handlers being installed more than once in the client causing you to run the same code multiple times in the client for a given client-side user event.

Comment: @Tuna According to the socket.io documentation you should be creating the custom namespace on the server side. http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#

Comment: @Tuna Then also accessing it client-side via `var socket =  io(/my-namespace);`

Comment: @lix This is only server side code sir, and am defining the namespace from the server side, the client is connecting correctly aswell, however some events fire once and some fire multiple times

Comment: @jfriend00 Am running a java client `Android` and my socket is in a single service class, all my socket events are in one service class. some events in my service class work perfectly without duplicate shots, let me cross check

Comment: @Tuna Have you tried working backwards and having only one of the three there and seeing the reaction?

Comment: @lix Yes, and on the server side, callback to event is sent only once, however the client receives it thrice

Comment: Perhaps the client has made three connections to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, there wasn't anything wrong with my socket server, the problem was on my client side `android`, my client could listen more than once, it's in the android Activity lifecycle. Basically my android developer told me that he called the listener in the `onResume` and `onPause` which made it listen twice. Anyway am not an android developer, i just hope no one gets the same issue.